# Microsoft Word: Formatting Paragraphs with Non Standard Indenting

Tags: microsoft-word, tabs, macos-mojave

I have a paragraph consisting of half a dozen lines, each terminated by a hard line feed [shift]-[enter]. Now I want to indent the second line of the paragraph by one tab, the third by two tabs, the fourth by three tabs, the fifth by two tabs, the sixth by one tab. How do I do this? When I try going to the second line and pressing the  key the entire paragraph of six lines is indented by one tab stop. What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if I was falling victim to Microsoft's "helpful" 'Replace text as you type' functionality. Turning this off seems to have solved the issue. I also discovered that [Ctrl]-[Tab] would let me do the same thing on a case by case basis. – gfhill just now   Edit   Delete